# How to combine the contents of two cells if a another cell contains specific characters/strings or parts thereof

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The issue:

I have cells containing strings, example:

```
Cell A     |   Cell B     |     Cell C     |     Cell D   |  Cell E  | .....
1234 256   |  5424H-84    |  47-1223-7z-334|  TARGET CELL | 12 fw e  | .....
```

What formula do I need to look at the contents of Cell C for the characters "7z" or even "23" or "z-3", if present then to combine cell A and Cell B in to Cell D?

I've tried many things that I can think of and yet either get 0 or blank lines...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("7z",C1,1),-1)>0,CONCATENATE(A1,B1))
```

Comment: Solved! Obviously not any of the variations I tried, and a slight change to it and it's perfect.

=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("7z",C1,1),-1)>0,CONCATENATE(A1& "-" &B1))

Comment: Excellent. Since we're using `CONCATENATE`, no need for the `&`: `=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("7z",C1,1),-1)>0,CONCATENATE(A1, "-", B1))`.